# Explictly providing labels to knitr::kable()?

Tags: r, knitr, kable

**knitr's** simple framework makes it easy to use tables. However, I am unsure how to explicitly provide a label.

In this **example**, the number supplied (1) is ignored in the caption.

```
knitr::kable(d1, caption = "Iris head", label = "1")
```

```
Table: Iris head

| Sepal.Length| Sepal.Width| Petal.Length| Petal.Width|Species |
|------------:|-----------:|------------:|-----------:|:-------|
|          5.1|         3.5|          1.4|         0.2|setosa  |
|          4.9|         3.0|          1.4|         0.2|setosa  |
|          4.7|         3.2|          1.3|         0.2|setosa  |
|          4.6|         3.1|          1.5|         0.2|setosa  |
|          5.0|         3.6|          1.4|         0.2|setosa  |
|          5.4|         3.9|          1.7|         0.4|setosa  |
```

Upon looking into `kable()`, the caption is created from two supporting functions: `kable_caption()` and `create_label()`

```
> getAnywhere(kable_caption)
A single object matching ‘kable_caption’ was found
It was found in the following places
  namespace:knitr
with value

function (label, caption, format) 
{
    if (is.null(label)) 
        label = opts_current$get("label")   #default is NULL
    if (is.null(label)) 
        label = NA
    if (!is.null(caption) && !is.na(caption) && !is.na(label)) 
        caption = paste0(
create_label(opts_knit$get("label.prefix")[["table"]],   #"tab:"  by default
            label,
 latex = (format == "latex")
), 
caption
)
   return(caption)
}

<bytecode: 0x00000147d346b820>
<environment: namespace:knitr>
```

The default NULL label becomes missing and is excluded from the caption.

```
> getAnywhere(create_label)
A single object matching ‘create_label’ was found
It was found in the following places
  namespace:knitr
with value

function (..., latex = FALSE) 
{
    if (isTRUE(opts_knit$get("bookdown.internal.label"))) {   #Default of option is NULL so condition by default is FALSE. 
        lab1 = "(\\#"
        lab2 = ")"
    }
    else if (latex) {
        lab1 = "\\label{"
        lab2 = "}"
    }
    else {
        return("")
    }
    paste(c(lab1, ..., lab2), collapse = "")
}
```

Due to the `return("")` line, a label will only be generated if `opts_knit$get("bookdown.internal.label")` is `TRUE`, the format is `latex`, and the caption is supplied (caption is not `NA` or not `NULL`). This implies that any user-supplied label will be ignored. The documentation is also not clear what class "label" should be: a number? a character?

**Question:** Can you explicitly assign a label to a `kable`?

**Note:** I realize this may be more appropriate on https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/new; however, in accordance with the author's guidelines, I am posting it here first.

Comment: How to understand: explicitly?

Comment: Great question, @manro. Explicitly means to tell `kable()` what the label should be, instead of relying on **knitr** to automatically generate the label.

Comment: Maybe I don't fully understand you, but we can add a label with using of pure LaTeX. Yes?

Comment: I added a **knitr** link to this question on the GitHub page: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/2088

Answer (score 0):

Is this that you need?

A **dataset** from your [next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70397659/changing-how-zeros-are-printed-in-sparse-tables-using-flextable) question:

````
```{r}
A <- tibble::as_tibble(matrix(c(rep(0, 9), rep(1,3)), nrow = 4, dimnames = list(NULL, LETTERS[1:3])))
```
````

Some code in **LaTeX**:

```
\begin{table}[hbtp]
\captionof{table}{My table made in kable}
\label{tab:caption}
\centering
`r knitr::kable(A)`
\end{table}
```

**Don't forget** to add these packages:

```
header-includes:
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{caption}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This should definitely work and may give Yihui and company something to think about. However, my question is to specify a label value as compared to letting it be the default ("NULL") -- i.e. `knir::kable(A, label = "1")`. In the question above. I'm saying that `label` can only be `NULL` for a label to be printed without exterior code to prompt it, as indicated above.  Is there a way to provide the same result using `label = "1"` or `label = 1` in `kable()` without the exterior code?