# Changing how zeros are printed in sparse tables using `flextable`

Tags: r, flextable

I have used `kable()` from **knitr** to generate nice-looking tables outputted in Microsoft Word. However, `kable()` was designed to be a simple table generator and can't offer all the advanced features that **flextable** has; for instance, the inclusion of a footer.

Sometimes, I want to print an overly sparse table and include it in a Microsoft Word document. Instead of printing zeros, I want to suppress them using the `zero.print` argument in `prettyNum()`.

For a `kable`, I can add a `format.arg()` argument to specify whether to print the zeros (which is passed to `format()` and then passed to `prettyNum()`.

Could a similar feature be added in **flextable**? This would enable **flextable** to do all the things a `kable` can do and then some, making it a worthwhile package. Probably the best function to add would be `colformat_num()`. Could an `...` argument be added that passes additional arguments to `prettyNum()` or `formatC()`?

```
  A <- tibble::as_tibble(matrix(c(rep(0, 9), rep(1,3)), nrow = 4, dimnames = list(NULL, LETTERS[1:3])))

knitr::kable(A, caption = "Example -- with zeros")
A   B   C
0   0   0
0   0   1
0   0   1
0   0   1
Example – with zeros

knitr::kable(A, caption = "Example -- zeros suppresed. A pattern in this example table is more easy to spot",
             format.args = list(zero.print = ".")  #Make all the zeros be a dot.
)
A   B   C
.   .   .
.   .   1
.   .   1
.   .   1
Example – zeros suppressed. A pattern in this example table is easier to spot

flextable::flextable(A)
```

Comment: Is this a coding question or a `flextable` feature request?

Comment: Could you just manually replace all the uninteresting values with a space character? If you're piping it to kable or flextable anyway, it shouldn't matter that you convert the matrix to character

Comment: `flextable` is on Github at https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable, so the way to make this happen is to make a suggestion in the issues there, or even better, code it yourself and submit it as a "pull request".

Comment: @Peter: Yes, it is both. I am relatively new to **flextable** so I thought I would ask here first. I did post it to `flextable` as suggested by the Stack Overflow community: https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable/issues/369

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can prepare our data before wrapping with `flextable` package.

````
```{r}
library(tidyverse)
library(flextable)

A <- tibble::as_tibble(matrix(c(rep(0, 9), rep(1,3)), nrow = 4, dimnames = list(NULL, LETTERS[1:3])))


A1 <- A %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, str_replace_all, pattern = "0", replacement = ".")


flextable(A1) %>% 
  set_caption(., "I'm a beautiful table")
```
````

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use any defined formatter and use it with function `set_formatter()`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(flextable)

A <- tibble::as_tibble(matrix(c(rep(0, 9), rep(1,3)), nrow = 4, dimnames = list(NULL, LETTERS[1:3])))

fun <- function(x) {
  z <- formatC(x)
  z[x < 0.001] <- "."
  z
}
fun_all_cols <- lapply(colnames(A), function(x) fun)
names(fun_all_cols) <- colnames(A)

flextable(A) %>% 
  set_formatter(values = fun_all_cols)
```

[image]